# Re-run jquery script when ajax call is made

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery float box plugin. The document is loaded and on a buttonpress an ajaxcall triggers box.php which parse the box `#floating-box` to be floated (the box is then showed on alla pages from now on). The problem is that the script which is within `$(document).ready(function(){..` does not find the box (if I refresh it works so the scipt is OK). I am novice but I guess this could be solved with some kind of `live`solution. Can someone guide me  in the right direction?

start of jquery script. the script works so the whole script itself is not of interest, rather how to re-run it when box.php have parsed the box `#floating-box` but still to run it on every document load since the box appears on all pages from now on and needs to float on them too.

```
var $floatingbox = $('#floating-box');

if($('#floating-container').length > 0){..
```

Comment: ok I found one solution to put the script within box.php which thus gets re-run but then the script is not together with the others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var url = "box.php";
    $("#id_of_button").click(function(){  
        $("#id_of_result").load(url, null, function(){  
                //put script here, it runs when ajax load is complete  
            });  ...
```

Comment: but then it does not run on every pageload. the ajax load is only used once when the box is added, then box.php is included with php and the floating script should also then be able to detect the box

Comment: what if you do `var myfloatingboxfunc = function() { //stuff };` and put myfloatingboxfunc in both the callback of the ajax and the document.ready ?  I would suggest setting the function to a variable like this in case it ever needs to be changed, it will only need to be done in one place.